# Custom shells displaying error - Cake PHP 3

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, cron, cakephp-3.0

Custom shells not working, I am using Cake PHP 3.

When I am creating a shell file to be used for cron job, example: HelloShell.php

Console under bin folder, when I run cake hello then, it returns class HelloShell could not loaded.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: You say CakePHP 3, but the shell clearly says CakePHP 1.3.14. Even more confusing is that (IIRC) 1.3 apps do not have a `bin` folder, instead the shell is in the `console` folder. That being said, you'll have to provide more information so that your problem becomes reproducible, like where exactly is the shell class  file created, what does the conent look like, are the access rights for the file set properly, etc...

Comment: Have you perhaps created a `cake` alias to an older version of CakePHP's `cake` command? The shell code being run is for CakePHP 1.3.14 not Cake 3! Try running `bin/cake hello` from the root of your project to make sure you're running the correct script.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty much straightforward

> your working path should be the same as your application path

1) You're not in the app path, you're in app/bin. So you should run the shell as

```
$ cd /var/www/html/cakephp
$ bin/cake hello
```

2) If your `cake` command is not linked to this particular binary, then you have to use the proper notation to run a bin in UNIX

```
$ cd /var/www/html/cakephp/bin
$ ./cake hello
```

Otherwise you could be calling a totally different `cake` in your system